# Waiting in pentaho kettle-spoon

Tags: open-source, pentaho, kettle

I am new to the Pentaho Kettle and I want to do multiple operations in a Transformation.
Firstly I am

1. inserting data from a text file to a main table.
2. Loading some of the columns from the main table to a 2nd table based on some conditions.

But the problem is only after completing the first step I have to do the 2nd step.   Because for the 2nd step i need the 1st step to be completed.

I can say that my first step is taking almost 20 mins..

Also in that same transformation i have to do other data loading from different table too..

I don't know kettle is providing a dedicated option to perform that like any switches or something like that.I have searched a lot in web but I didn't got any ...

So can anyone help me in solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

that's what exactly the "Blocking Step" do, give a try.

http://www.nicholasgoodman.com/bt/blog/2008/06/25/ordered-rows-in-kettle/

Answer (score 0):

Or split your transform into multiple transforms and orchestrate them in a Job. If your transforms are simple, I would tend towards using the blocking steps. But using them too much I find makes the transforms messy and complex. Wrapping Transforms in Jobs usually gives you more control.

Brian